# Enabling Enhanced Notes in scratch org

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx, richtext-notes

I have a package that I'd like to develop using Salesforce DX and whose functionality includes inserting `ContentNote` objects. Since my scratch orgs by default do not have the enhanced note feature activated, pushing source results in "Invalid type: ContentNote" errors.

Is there any way to [enable enhanced notes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_setup_enable.htm&type=5) from either SFDX or the Metadata API? I've reviewed the [Scratch Org Definition File](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm) documentation and cannot determine how to activate this feature, nor is there a `NoteSettings` entity in the Metadata API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nowadays, here is the setting:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "enhancedNotesSettings": {
            "enableEnhancedNotes": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

An answer was posted to a similar question in the Salesforce DX group in the Salesforce Trailblazer community. For posterity, the relevant feature id is "NotesReservedPref01", hence:

```
"orgPreferences" : {
  "enabled": ["ChatterEnabled", "NotesReservedPref01"]
}
```

in the scratch org definition.

Comment: In winter 19, `orgPreferences` has been deprecated (and will be removed in spring) in favor of `settings`, which uses the Metadata API settings.  Unfortunately, while `NotesReservedPref01` exists in Metadata API's `orgPreferenceSettings`, setting it in the scratch org def ( `"settings" : {"orgPreferenceSettings" : { "NotesReservedPref01" : true } } `) isn't working for me.

Comment: Also: you **should** be able deploy this setting as part of your DX code, by adding `force-app/main/default/settings/OrgPreference.settings-meta.xml`, and setting `NotesReservedPref01` in there (see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_orgpreferencesettings.htm).  But in my testing this isn't working either, so instead I do an MDAPI deploy prior to pushing source for the first time.  In fact, I had the same issue with `EnhancedEmailEnabled` (and the same fix) so I'm thinking it's an issue with org prefs in the scratch org def and in the DX source.

Comment: @JasonClark The SFDX team are really active on their Success Community group - they may respond if you post these notes there.

Answer (score 4):

As @JasonClark said, the orgPreferences has been deprecated in Winter 19. He was on the right track, but the settings should now use lowerCamelCase and the "n" should be lowercase.

```
"settings" : "orgPreferenceSettings" : { "notesReservedPref01" : true }
```